# Android error cannot acess AbstractSafeParcelable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm tryind add firebase remote config to my project, but it is conflicting with the version of my gms, the error code:

> Error:(674, 25) error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
>   class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

And when i click its send me for this method of my project:

```
    protected void RequestLocation() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000); // for this line
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

I tried some suggestions that I found in the stackoverflow itself, like changing the version of gms to 10.0.1 but ends up generating another error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.2.

My original build.gradle can be checked here:`apply plugin:

```
'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.editable.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.4.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gcm-src.jar')
    compile project(':firebase_plugin')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Comment: It's not clear what you changed when you used 10.0.1.  Did you change all of the four `play-services-*` libs to 10.0.1 so that nothing was 9.0.2?

Comment: Yes i change all

`    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'`
To 10.0.1 and its begin other errors

Comment: Have you tried changing `firebase-config` to 9.0.2?

Comment: I tried switching to 9.6.1, it worked, but then another error happened, but I managed to tidy it up after moving the project and clearing the project Tnx.